# Android : Getting String value from onClick method to onCreate above

Tags: android, string

Well this might be a very noob question since i'm new to Android but i was wondering how to get a String value that is inside `onClick` to the `onCreate` above.

It's basically an `EditText` converted into a String

```
daa = txt.getText().toString();
```

I've used it globally but it doesn't seem to fetch the value.

`onCreate`:

```
sp3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.hh);

    sp3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance(); 




        /*SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        String formattedDate = df.format(c1.getTime());
        */

        int hour = c1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
Log.d("dp", ""+daa);
            edsp3.setText(pickup_hour[position]);
            String hourSelected = pickup_hour[position];
             if(Integer.parseInt(hourSelected)<hour)
                                 {
                                     Toast.makeText(OnlineBooking.this, "Choose greater hour",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

}

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });
    ArrayAdapter b3 = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, pickup_hour);

    b3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sp3.setAdapter(b3);
```

`onClick`:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == btnCalendar) {

        // Process to get Current Date
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Launch Date Picker Dialog
        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                            int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        // Display Selected date in textbox

                         if (year < mYear)
                                view.updateDate(mYear,mMonth,mDay);

                            if (monthOfYear < mMonth && year == mYear)
                                view.updateDate(mYear,mMonth,mDay);

                            if (dayOfMonth < mDay && year == mYear && monthOfYear == mMonth)
                                view.updateDate(mYear,mMonth,mDay);

                        txtDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-"
                                + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        Date newDate2 = c.getTime();
        dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(newDate2.getTime());
        dpd.show();
        daa = txtDate.getText().toString();
        Log.d("deepee", ""+daa);

    }   }
```

I'm trying to get String `daa` value inside `onItemSelected` in `onCreate`

How can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not? post your code

Comment: Show the code you have written that is involved.

Comment: Post your full code...

Comment: @MetaldroiD theres no log visible :(

Comment: I'm trying to get String `daa` value from `onClick` inside `onItemSelected` in onCreate

Comment: @MetaldroiD Why don't you get the text directly in `onItemSelected`like `daa = txtDate.getText().toString();`

Comment: @Hariharan is correct, else you will hve to click the button first in order to set the value in daa and then get the value in the onItmSelected

Comment: Okay now i think this is working since i got the text directly in `onItemSelected` like `daa = txtDate.getText().toString();`

Thank you.